# binding using a composite property in wpf

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a class called Person which comprises of another object 'Contact' which holds the person address. I am binding the person class to the wpf grid. How can i bind a property inside Address?

```
Class Person 
--------------
string Name{get;set;}
Contact Address{get;set;}
int id{get;set;}

Class Contact 
----------------

    string City;
    string State;
    string Country;
```

I need to bind to

> Person.Contact.City

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the binding path to `Address.City`. This must be a property not a public field.